# What syntax does labview use when communicating

Tags: vb.net, labview

I'm using the same code that is still working for a new version of equipment the company the bought.

I can't communicate with the equipment in vb in visual studio (the language of the last code I wrote).  But I can make a simple code in LabVIEW to see if the equipment is communicating and it is.

So, my question is what code is labview sending to the equipment?
The only thing I see from the LabVIEW GUI is `*IDN?\n`

Is that the same as what I writing?

`mySerialport.WriteLine("*idn?" + Chr(10))`

Comment: How is this different from [your last post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47895993/1070452) except being much more broad?

Comment: If you wan't any help, at least post the labview code (block diagram).

Answer (score 2):

```
*IDN?\n
```

is not the same as :

```
mySerialport.WriteLine("*idn?" + Chr(10))
```

The former is capitalized while the later is not and it may cause an issue depending on the instrument.

You are using the serial port, so the most important thing to consider is the baud rate.  It is possible that the later model equipment your company purchased has a different baud rate to the one that was used previously.

If you want to see exactly the data that LabVIEW is sending, you can use NI IO Trace or a non NI serial port monitor such as listed [here](https://thecodeisbroken.wordpress.com/2016/08/11/portmon-i-forgot-about-you/)

Answer (score 0):

The question isn’t what language LabVIEW uses. LabVIEW is a programming environment with library APIs to speak to lots of hardware and the ability for anyone to write code to speak to even more hardware. The question is “what language does the HARDWARE speak?” To answer that, you’d post what kind of hardware it is and probably go to the manufacturer’s website for a spec sheet.

“*IDN?/n” looks like a GPIB command, which is just a framework serial protocol. You’d need the spec sheet of the hardware to know the particular commands that your hardware understands.

PS: LabVIEW doesn’t have a GUI showing anything about hardware communication. You have an application written in LabVIEW that has a GUI that is displaying information. You can edit the program to print out more info if you want, just like you could in VB. Complaining about the “LabVIEW GUI” in this case is equivalent to complaining about the Visual Studio GUI when the problem is with the program you’ve written in VS!

Comment: thanks for the input ... not sure what I'm doing in labview (as you see) ... I do I can communicate with it.

Comment: *from manufacturing website: Send *IDN?<CR><LF> (just to ensure that your application sends a carriage return and/or line feed) ..... which is what I thought I was doing.

Comment: Chr(10) is not the same as CR+LF. Ten is just the carriage return character. WriteLine("*idn?" + Chr(10) + Chr(13)) is what you need.

Comment: \n is the platform new line, which on Windows is 2 characters, both CR AND LF.

Answer (score 0):

"The only thing I see from the labview GUI is *IDN?/n"

That sounds more like you are using the VISA Test Panel in MAX (Measurement and Automation eXplorer).  It is related to LabVIEW in that it is also a tool developed by National Instruments (NI).  But it does not sound like you have actually touched LabVIEW itself.

As was already stated, *IDN?\n is a typical command that an instrument that follows the SCPI messaging standard.  On a Windows system, that is usually the same as "*idn?" + Chr(13) + Chr(10).

Answer (score 0):

As SeanJ pointed out *IDN?\n is not the same as "idn?". Further, make sure that space character in your calling method is visible. Sometimes machines require you to manually type "\r\n" for complete carriage return.